# Clojure tests running out of order?

Tags: database, unit-testing, clojure

I have an application with a unit test.  In this test I am creating a user
account and then testing it.  Then I modify it and test the modified
version.  The problem is, it seems to be doing some things out of order.  Am
I wrong?  Either way, how do I fix it?

It seems to me that when I run the test, then modify the database AFTER the test

In this version, it works-- no errors:

```
(ns myapp.db.account-test
  (:use expectations)
  (:require
    [myapp.db         :as DB]
    [myapp.db.account :as Account]
    ))

(defn- $reset-database
  "Reset the database to a pristine state."
  []
  (DB/create-db))

($reset-database)
(let [acct-1 {:email "one@email.com" :username "user-one" :password "goodpwd1"}
      acct-2 {:email "two@email.com" :username "user-two" :password "goodpwd2"}]
  (Account/create acct-1)
  (let [db-acct (Account/seek {:email (:email acct-1)})]
    (expect (:email    acct-1) (:email    db-acct))
    (expect (:username acct-1) (:username db-acct))

    (expect true  (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1) :password "goodpwd1"}))
    (expect false (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1) :password "badpwd"}))

  ;; Now try to change some attributes of the account
  #_(Account/modify acct-1 acct-2)
)
```

then...

```
myapp 10:28 PM ~/Projects/myapp/myapp.net/code/myapp $ lein test myapp.db.account-testPicked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
Rewriting src/cljx to target/generated/clj (clj) with features #{clj} and 0 transformations.
Rewriting src/cljx to target/generated/cljs (cljs) with features #{cljs} and 1 transformations.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar

lein test myapp.db.account-test

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Ran 4 tests containing 4 assertions in 171 msecs
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

But if I uncomment the last line, the 'prior' tests fail.

```
  ...
  ;; Now try to change some attributes of the account
  (Account/modify acct-1 acct-2)
)
```

then ...

```
myapp 10:40 PM ~/Projects/myapp/myapp.net/code/myapp $ lein test myapp.db.account-testPicked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
Rewriting src/cljx to target/generated/clj (clj) with features #{clj} and 0 transformations.
Rewriting src/cljx to target/generated/cljs (cljs) with features #{cljs} and 1 transformations.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar

lein test myapp.db.account-test

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

failure in (account_test.clj:21) : myapp.db.account-test
(expect
 true
 (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1), :password "goodpwd1"}))

  act-msg: exception in actual: (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1), :password "goodpwd1"})
    threw: class java.lang.NullPointerException -
           com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil$check (SCryptUtil.java:74)
           on (core.clj:41)
           on (account.clj:109)
           on (account_test.clj:21)

failure in (account_test.clj:22) : myapp.db.account-test
(expect
 false
 (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1), :password "badpwd"}))

  act-msg: exception in actual: (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1), :password "badpwd"})
    threw: class java.lang.NullPointerException -
           com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCryptUtil$check (SCryptUtil.java:74)
           on (core.clj:41)
           on (account.clj:109)
           on (account_test.clj:22)

Ran 4 tests containing 4 assertions in 234 msecs
0 failures, 2 errors.
```

In case it matters, the relevant part of myapp.db.account is:

```
(defn seek
  "Get an account by email address"
  [{:keys [email]}]
  (row-to-hash (get-account-by-email {:email email})))

(defn modify
  "Modify an account."
  [{current-email :email}
   {new-email     :email new-username :username new-password :password}]

  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [connection db-env/spec]
    (let [current (seek {:email current-email})]

      (update-email-by-email! {:current_email current-email :new_email new-email}))))

(defn authenticate
  "Try to authenticate given an identifier and a password.
  Note that this returns a false case in the case of actual falsity, but nil
  in the case of a poorly formed query (such as missing credentials)"
  [{:keys [id email username password]}]
  (and
    password
    (scrypt/verify
      ;; compare this password attempt
      password
      ;; with this hash from the db (when possible)
      (:passhash
        (first
          (cond
            ;; Branch on which field is present.
            id       (get-authorization-fields-by-id       {:id id})
            email    (get-authorization-fields-by-email    {:email email})
            username (get-authorization-fields-by-username {:username username})
            ;; Default to false
            :else nil))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be running `lein test`, you should be using `lein expectations` (which requires a plugin in your project.clj):

```
:plugins [[lein-expectations "0.0.7"]]
```

`expectations` are called upon jvm shutdown. My guess is that `lein test` is compiling your file which evaluates your db modifications, and the expectations run after that. It's fine until you introduce the change you'd want to run *after* your expectations.

To fix this, include the code you want to run within your expectation.  Here's an example using your code from above.  It uses the 'more-> macro from the expect library.

```
(let [acct-1 {:email "one@email.com" :username "user-one" :password "goodpwd1"}
      acct-2 {:email "two@email.com" :username "user-two" :password "goodpwd2"}]

  (expect 
    (more->
      true (do ($reset-database)
               (Account/create acct-1)
               (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1) :password "goodpwd1"}))
      false (do ($reset-database)
                (Account/create acct-1)
                (Account/authenticate {:email (:email acct-1) :password "badpwd"})))))
```

Comment: I switched to `$> lein expectations myapp.db.account-test` (following the instructions on the `expectations` website) but I see the exact same behavior.

Comment: Try making the change inside of your expectations (e.g. `(expect true (do (modify...) (stuff that relies on the change)))`. Otherwise all code that is evaluated as you compile will run before the expectations.

Comment: Thanks, I was going down this path as well.  It turns out that's the right answer (at least, it works for me).  I'm going to modify your answer to include an example of the working solution.